# Finding Jenkins view from Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins

We have different Jenkins views for different teams for easier tracking. We have another view 'All' which lists all the jobs in Jenkins.

Now, if I navigate to a job from 'All' views, I can't make out which other view it belongs to thereby making it hard to find responsible team.

Is there a way to find in what all views a particular job shows up?

Answer (score 5):

use the script console to find out:-

```
def findAllViews(name) {
    def jen = Jenkins.getInstance();        
    def views = jen.getViews()

    for(def view in views) {
        if(view.contains(jen.getItem(name))== true){
            println view.getDisplayName()
        }
    }
}

findAllViews("<jobname>")
```

Comment: Late in the game, but `gertViews()` doesn't get all the views. I've tried `getAllViews()` also to no avail.